# ¿Cómo usar Sockets en Android con Delphi?

Tags: android, arduino, socket, delphi, tcpip

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la que me gustaría recibir la temperatura a través de un Arduino. Creo que utilizar Sockets es una excelente forma de comunicación, pero no tengo idea de cómo utilizar Sockets en una aplicación Android hecha con Delphi.

¿Es diferente de cómo se utiliza en Delphi compilado para Windows?

Comment: Te recomendaría que revises el framework de [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) para android por sobre abrir sockets directamente. Te va a ahorrar varios dolores de cabeza.

Comment: @jachguate, ¿Cómo quieres realizar la comunicación? ¿Bluetooth? ¿Un servidor que maneje peticiones?

Comment: @Jaime, la comunicación es TCP/IP a un socket en un servidor accesible vía lan/wan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las Indy "de siempre" que vienen con delphi y que están disponibles también para las plataformas móviles.

Otra opción que puedes mirar es si puedes realizar la comunicación vía bluetooth.